# Display the selected attribute option name near the label in Woocommerce variable product

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I want to display the name of the selected attribute next to the label.

```
<th class="label">
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?></label> 
    <?php 
    $brand_terms = get_the_terms($post, 'pa_spieki');
    $brand_string = ''; // Reset string
    foreach ($brand_terms as $term) :
    $brand_string .= $term->name . ' ';
    endforeach;

    echo $brand_string;
    ?>
</th>
```

Unfortunately, my code returns the entire list, not just the selected attribute.

[image]

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manage that on server side with PHP, JavaScript is required.

**Update:** For multiple main product attributes, **each separated in different products**.

Try the following code replacement:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_specific_selected_attribute_term_name', 25);
function display_specific_selected_attribute_term_name() {
    global $product;

    if ( !$product->is_type('variable') ) {
        return; // Exit if it's not a variable product
    }

    // Here define the main attribute taxonomies (affected to different products)
    $attribute_taxonomies =  array('pa_spieki', 'pa_kolor-dostawki');

    // Loop through the main attribute taxonomies
    foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $attribute_taxonomy ) {
        if ( $product->get_attribute($attribute_taxonomy) ) {
            $taxonomy = $attribute_taxonomy; 
        }
    }
    
    if ( ! isset($taxonomy) ) {
        return; // Exit if no matched attributes affected to the current product
    }

    wc_enqueue_js("const selAttr = 'select#{$taxonomy}',  
        selAttrOption = selAttr+' option:selected', 
        selLabel = 'label[for={$taxonomy}]', 
        selSpan  = 'span.for-{$taxonomy}';
    
    $(selLabel).after(' <span class=\"for-{$taxonomy}\"></span>');

    function displayAttrSelectedOptionText(){
        const textValue = $(selAttr).val() != '' ? $(selAttrOption).text() : '';
        $(selSpan).text(textValue);
    }

    displayAttrSelectedOptionText();

    $('form.cart').on('change', 'select#{$taxonomy}', function() {
        displayAttrSelectedOptionText();
    })");
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Comment: Thank you very much it works well. I would like to repeat this for one more attribute group. How can I modify this?

Comment: Can you provide the 2 other attribute taxonomy (starting with "pa_") like "pa_spieki", please.

Comment: pa_kolor-dostawki and pa_rozmiar-stolu - but I just want it for pa_spieki and pa_kolor-dostawki

Comment: Just for those 2 (pa_spieki and pa_kolor-dostawki)… I Will make that later on adding an addition to this answer, so for tomorrow. Are they both on the product or separated in different products?

Comment: Separated in different products. Will this make a difference for those attributes that are used in one product or in different ones?

Comment: @PatrykBanach In this case it should be very easy… I have updated my code. Try it (untested on my side).